# Adding mouse location as parameter to command wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, eventtrigger

I have a user control and I added it to my view :

```
<uc:myImageWrapper  DataContext="{Binding C}"/>
```

And now I want the following :
When user is clicking on the control I want to invoke command in view model:
I added the event trigger and it works nice :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseClickCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The problem is that I want to pass  as parameter the x and y of the click relatively to my user control. I also want to pass what button (left or right) was clicked. 
How can I do this.
Thank you,

Matvey

Comment: You can create a `Behavior` to set the `CommandParamter` of the command. If you can find the right event to make it work before your command is executed it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain more, please ?

Comment: You can create a `Behavior` in the UI to calculate for you. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I will look for some example. But how can I send it to view model?
I want to send MouseEventArgs object. Not only coordinates..

Comment: `InvokeCommandAction` has a property called `CommandParameter` which is a dependency property, so you can bind it to a dependency property in your `Behavior`.

Comment: Do you have some example of what you exactly meaning ? May be some link ?
Thanks a lot!